# Handle Design Button in Android

Tags: android, android-custom-view, imagebutton, handle

I have created a luck wheel which spin with a simple button now.

[image: Press button will spin the wheel]

Want to create a handle/button like this to spin the Wheel.

[image]

Any help or clue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create a custom view and draw spin handle using Canvas. You can draw a circle and write text number above it or you can use pre-rendered spin handle images with animation moving from up to down. Then you must listen for onTouch event and if it is top to down movement then you animate pre-rendered images. If there are no more touch input you can simply draw first pre-rendered image.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use Rotation animation 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1600"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:toDegrees="358" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the "Custom Backgrounds" section in here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html

It covers changing the button's image based on the current state of the button.